# How to include Mapbox secret token in Github Actions CI pipeline

Tags: android, continuous-integration, github-actions, mapbox

I need to include Mapbox secret token to my CI pipeline. At the moment it is stored as a secret in Github and locally in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. At the moment it just returns
`Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/android/10.9.0/android-10.9.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized`

```
name: Check PR

on: push
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  #workflow_dispatch:
env:
  SECRET: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-
      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Install node dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Load API Token from secrets
        env:
          SECRET: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
        run: echo SECRET=\"$SECRET\" > ./local.properties

      - name: Build the app

        run: yarn run build-android-staging-release

      - name: Upload apk
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: debug apk
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

I have tried more or less similar approaches what is in the CI snippet. I am expecting that Mapbox doesn't return 401.